# Programmable FGMOS’ simulation model using Virtuoso

Tags: transistors, mosfet, eda, cadence

I know that one can introduce programmability in FGMOS transistor using Fowler-Nordheim Tunneling and hot electron injection, but am unable to implement this idea in cadence design tool virtuoso. I would like to know how to generate this equivalent model of programmable FGMOS in virtuoso? What are the circuit components that need to be added in order to achieve tunneling and injection in a FGMOS?[image]

Comment: Do you want to model _only_ tunneling and injection into the floating gate, or do you want to model normal MOS operations as well? These processes have time scales that are many orders of magnitude different so I'm not sure it makes sense to model them together.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I wish to model tunneling and injection into the FGMOS only. What I am trying to do is to use these FGMOS and program their threshold voltages by tunneling and injection, and implement a programmable operational transresistance amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

The following reference may help:
["A Comprehensive Simulation Model for
Floating Gate Transistors"](http://sjrapp.com/pubs/rapp_thesis.pdf) Steven Joseph Rapp, Master Theses. WVU 2010.

Juan del Valle